# Site crashes when I use 6 or more images on canvas on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am trying drawing large image with height like 12000 where I need to draw seven images with almost similar height, I am able to draw 5 images but it crashes the site when I draw 6 or more images on canvas. Below is the screenshot of what happens when I draw 6 or more images in canvas :-
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrIbB.png)

Can I get to know what's the issue I am getting? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I think you should test your site on a testing website first because it may be a problem with your phone RAM, Hence, crashing the site.

Comment: Canvas uses ram?

Comment: You should tell which exception lets your app crash. And post the stack trace.

Comment: Of course. Everything which your computer is doing uses RAM including rendering HTML.